# WPF Window Inheritance

Tags: c#, wpf, inheritance

I have an application that will run in two modes, each with very similar displays. The application is supposed to allow easy modification of a user interface. One of the features is that it has to display the user interface. Both of these windows look the same, just one has more menus than the other.

I'd like to just create a base template (the user visual) and then inherit it for the editor. That way if one interface changes, both of them change. But this doesn't seem to be possible using WPF. I try to inherit and I get warnings about hiding members. I also don't see how I'm going to append new menus to the base template.

Is what I'm trying to do possible? Is there a better way that I'm supposed to be doing this? It seems like I'm fighting the way that they want me to make the application.

Answer (score 0):

If I got your question properly, all you have to do is create a [style](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745683.aspx) for a window in shared resources. When user changes a style it will be automatically applied to every control that uses this style.

For the custom parts you could use [ContentPresenters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163497.aspx) and [custom controls](http://www.wpftutorial.net/HowToCreateACustomControl.html)..